# Groups and filters - best practices?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Is there a better way to format this:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf|ajax'), function()
{
    Route::post('site-manager-gateway/log-in', 'SiteManagerGatewayController@postLogIn');
});

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth|csrf|ajax'), function()
{
    Route::controller('/site-manager-gateway', 'SiteManagerGatewayController');
});
```

For all my site-manager-gateway controller routes I need to filter with auth, csrf, and ajax. But the part of the controller that checks for log in can't be filtered with auth - as the user is yet to log in.

I was wondering, is there a better way to write this code?

Comment: I tend to add `csrf` and `ajax` in my controller set up, rather than to the routes...  Especially since `csrf` doesn't really apply to GET requests.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can just do the one group with all common before filters and then specify the *additional* before filter either on the route (exemplified below) or in the controller.

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf|ajax'), function()
{
    Route::post('site-manager-gateway/log-in', 'SiteManagerGatewayController@postLogIn');
    Route::controller('site-manager-gateway', array('before' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'SiteManagerGatewayController'));
});
```